# Keyboard keys - sometimes these five keys (RUIOP) stop working simultaneously

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes, the keys RUIOP suddenly stop working for 10-60 seconds, no matter how hard/long I press the key, I've cleaned the keyboard, etc. I just hit random keys or wait until it works again. Didn't manage to google any similar issue

It's just those 5 keys (maybe more I didn't spotted), when the problem occurs it does it on those 5 keys at the same time. When it's gone, there isn't any issue with typing normally as if the keyboard was totally fine.

Keyboard model is a HP KU-0841, been working like a charm for years

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Sounds broken. Try a new keyboard, see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat of an educated guess: The RUIOP keys use a single line in the keyboard matrix from the keyboard controller, and the electrical trace for this line has a weak point somewhere.

If you hit keys or move the keyboard, the vibrations may cause minmal shifts in the substrate of the trace, causing it to work or not work seemingly randomly.

Either open up the keyboard and see if you can find the weak trace and fix it, or buy a new keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look inside. I don't have any idea what I'm looking at, but is it normal that the two thin films seem "bounded" at two specific location ? As if it was soldered or that the plastic melted together. https://imgur.com/a/x1SheYT

Comment: Probably not, but from the photos, that doesn't seem to touch an electrical trace, so it shouldn't matter. If you can identify the RUIOP keys on the film(s), you should be able to identify the trace that's possibly damaged.